# Need help in creating search box in Php

Tags: php, html, search-box

i'm just started to learn php few weak's before.. i'm working on a search box but i cant get the result

```
  <html>
  <head><title>Search Form</title></head>
  <body>
        <form action="12.html" method="GET">
               <input type="text" name="keyword" id="keyword width="50" value="" />
               <input type="submit" value="Search"/>
  </form>
  </body>
  </html>
  <?php
  $searchfor = $_GET['keyword'];
  $file = '12.html';
  $contents = file_get_contents($file);
  $pattern = preg_quote($searchfor, '/');
  $pattern = "/^.*$pattern.*\$/m";
  if(preg_match_all($pattern, $contents, $matches)){
  echo "Found matches:<br />";
  echo implode("<br />", $matches[0]);
  }
  else{
  echo "No matches found";
  fclose ($file); 
  }
  ?>
```

my content for searching is in 12.html file. if i type the word in the search box the whole body of my page is coming as the result i need the specific line or the word in it. even i type a word that which is not present in my content its. my body of my files is showing i don't know where i did the mistake can any one guide me in it.

Comment: Your form is going to 12.html, when it should really be going to the current PHP page you are on. Change the action to "whateverthispageiscalled.php" and then test?

Answer (score 0):

First, there are errors in your HTML syntax.  You want the action to point to your script.

```
<form action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>" method="GET">
```

There is an error in your input item.

```
<input type="text" name="keyword" id="keyword" width="50" value="" />


<?php
$searchfor = $_GET['keyword'];
$file = '12.html';
$contents = file_get_contents($file);
$pattern = preg_quote($searchfor, '/');
$pattern = '/'.$pattern.'/m';
if(preg_match_all($pattern, $contents, $matches)){
    echo "Found " . count($matches) . " matches:<br />";
//here you are imploding the entire array;
    echo implode("<br />", $matches);
}
else{
    echo "No matches found";
    fclose ($file); 
}
?>
```

I don't understand why would you want to implode the matches because that would just list the same word however many times it was found.  If you want to find the specific line you can try this.

```
<?php
$lines = explode('\n',$contents);
$lineNum = 1;
$linesFound = array();
foreach ($lines as $line){
    if (preg_match($pattern, $line)){
        $linesFound[] = $lineNum;
    }
    $lineNum++
}
if (!empty($linesFound)){
}
echo "Keyword found on line(s): 
?>
```

Comment: its not working its redirecting to my 12.html file itself not showing my key word i'm searching